# Estimators with latent variables and transforming corresponding coefficients

Tags: stata, logit, latent-variable

I using a logit model. The problem I have is basically my dependent variable $Y$ cannot assume a negative value so I am using a latent version of this $Y^*$ which makes my $Y$ zero whenever it is negative. I estimated coefficients by using $Y^*$. Is there way to convert these coefficients to the corresponding original equation? That is, suppose the original equation is $Y=\beta X$ with error terms. I have estimated $Y^*=\alpha X$ is there way to convert this $\alpha$ into $\beta$? I am using STATA. Thanks for any help in advance.

Comment: I'm a bit confused here.  Are you fitting a binary logit model, multinomial, or ordinal?  In each of these cases, the outcome is categorical, so I'm not sure how the problem with negative values for your outcome variable would arise.  More information on what it is you are trying to model (maybe some dummy data or first few lines of your dataset with the relevant variables shown) would be helpful

Comment: @MarquisdeCarabas  The idea is to estimate the number of medal wins in olympic games (Y) with bunch of variables on the right hand side. So since $Y^*$ assigns the value $0$ to $Y$ whenever it is negative.

Comment: Since your outcome is count, logit is not appropriate the appropriate model for you to use, unless you are categorizing the number of medals, i.e. "1" = 1-3 medals, "2" = 4-6 medals, "3" = 3-9 medals, etc.  Poisson, negative binomial, or their zero-inflated flavors--most countries will probably have zero medals--would be more suited for this type of outcome. However, I have a question for you: how can the number of medals be negative?